# How is a multiple-outputs deep learning model trained?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, multipleoutputs

I think I do not understand the multiple-output networks.

Althrough i understand how the implementation is made and i succesfully trained one model like this, i don't understand how a multiple-outputs deep learning network is trained. I mean, what is happening inside the network during training?

Take for example this network from the [keras functional api guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

[image]

You can see the two outputs (aux_output and main_output). How is the backpropagation working?

My intuition was that the model does two backpropagations, one for each output. 
Each backpropagation then updates the weight of the layers preceding the exit.
**But it appears that's not true:** from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213471/how-does-keras-handle-backpropagation-in-multiple-outputs/57220038#57220038) (SO), i got the information that there is only one backpropagation despite the multiple outputs; **the used loss is weighted according to the outputs.**

But still, i don't get how the network and its auxiliary branch are trained; how are the auxiliary branch weights updated as it is not connected directly to the main output? Is the part of the network which is between the root of the auxiliary branch and the main output concerned by the the weighting of the loss? Or the weighting influences only the part of the network that is connected to the auxiliary output?

Also, i'm looking for good articles about this subject. I already read GoogLeNet / Inception articles ([v1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842v1.pdf),[v2-v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf)) as this network is using auxiliary branches.

Comment: https://medium.com/@14prakash/back-propagation-is-very-simple-who-made-it-complicated-97b794c97e5c might help. Shows you the math behind the back-propagation.

Comment: Thanks for your question, however it is more concerned with theoretical aspects of machine learning and therefore is not suitable for SO. You might have a better chance of getting an answer on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Further, requesting articles, tutorials or off-site resources are not allowed on SO.

Comment: I understand your point. This question is strongly correlated to understanding how Keras functional API is working there, as this architecture is its main example. So i thought it was relevant to post it there. I'll move the question in CrossValidated if i don't find my answers here after the end of the bounty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keras calculations are graph based and use **only one optimizer**.

The optimizer is also a part of the graph, and in its calculations it gets the gradients of the whole group of weights. (Not two groups of gradients, one for each output, but one group of gradients for the entire model).

Mathematically, it's not really complicated, you have a final loss function made of:

```
loss = (main_weight * main_loss) + (aux_weight * aux_loss) #you choose the weights in model.compile
```

All defined by you. Plus a series of other possible weights (sample weights, class weights, regularizer terms, etc.)

Where:

- `main_loss` is a `function_of(main_true_output_data, main_model_output)`
- `aux_loss` is a `function_of(aux_true_output_data, aux_model_output)`

And the gradients are just `∂(loss)/∂(weight_i)` for all weights.

Once the optimizer has the gradients, it performs its optimization step once.

**Questions:**

> how are the auxiliary branch weights updated as it is not connected directly to the main output?

- You have **two output datasets**. One dataset for `main_output` and another dataset for `aux_output`. You must pass them to `fit` in `model.fit(inputs, [main_y, aux_y], ...)`
- You also have two loss functions, one for each, where `main_loss` takes `main_y` and `main_out`; and `aux_loss` takex `aux_y` and `aux_out`.
- The two losses are summed: `loss = (main_weight * main_loss) + (aux_weight * aux_loss)`
- The gradients are calculated for the function `loss` once, and this function connects to the entire model.

  - The `aux` term will affect `lstm_1` and `embedding_1` in backpropagation.
  - Consequently, in the next forward pass (after weights are updated) it will end up influencing the main branch. (If it will be better or worse only depends on whether the aux output is useful or not)

> Is the part of the network which is between the root of the auxiliary branch and the main output concerned by the the weighting of the loss? Or the weighting influences only the part of the network that is connected to the auxiliary output?

The weights are plain mathematics. You will define them in `compile`:

```
model.compile(optimizer=one_optimizer, 

              #you choose each loss   
              loss={'main_output':main_loss, 'aux_output':aux_loss},

              #you choose each weight
              loss_weights={'main_output': main_weight, 'aux_output': aux_weight}, 

              metrics = ...)
```

And the loss function will use them in `loss = (weight1 * loss1) + (weight2 * loss2)`.
The rest is the mathematical calculation of `∂(loss)/∂(weight_i)` for each weight.