# How does Keras handle backpropagation in multiple outputs

Tags: keras, deep-learning, backpropagation

For a network architecture like this:

```
          +---+   
input1--->| CNN | -------|
           +---+         |  
                         |
           +---+      +-------+          +-------+ 
input2--->| CNN | ----| Concat|-----|----|  VGG  |---- Main_out
           +---+      +-------+     |    +-------+   
                          |         |
           +---+          |         |
input3--->| CNN | --------|        Aux_out
           +---+
```

How does the backpropagation flow go? I mean, there are two backpropagation steps? Or the only one that comes from the `Main_out` updates the weights.

I am using loss weights for each output:

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=OPT,metrics=["accuracy"],
            loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2}
```

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have better main_out accuracy when the aux_out is included. I know that aux_out could help with vanishing gradient problem. I just want to understand how Keras handle backpropagation in this situation. Like does the first three CNN weights are updated twice? One updating from the  main_out and another update from the aux-out?

Answer (score 3):

The losses for different outputs are combined into a final loss according to `loss_weights`,

```
final_loss = loss_main + 0.2*loss_aux
```

the parameters will be updated with respect to this loss by one backpropagation step at each iteration.

Comment: So, there are two backpropagation steps with the same loss? One that comes from Main_out and other from Aux_out?

Comment: @JulesR I have edited the answer, hope it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot post a comment as i don't have enough reputation so i'm posting my question as an answer. Sorry for that but i'm struggling to have information on that subject)

As i asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149476/how-is-a-multiple-outputs-model-trained), i also have trouble understanding how it works; as JulesR, i have better "main ouput" accuracy when adding "aux_out" using another network architecture.

If i understand dontloo's response (please correct me if i'm wrong), there is only one backpropagation despite the multiple outputs but the loss used is weighted according to the outputs. So for JulesR's network, the update of the VGG weights during backpropagation is also influenced by this weighted loss (therefore by the "intermediate output")? If yes, isn't it strange regarding the fact that the VGG network is after this output?

Also, @JulesR has mentioned that auxiliary outputs can helps the vanishing gradient problem. Do you have some links about articles speaking of the effects of auxiliary outputs?

Comment: Aux outputs used un GoogLeNet see
 https://medium.com/coinmonks/paper-review-of-googlenet-inception-v1-winner-of-ilsvlc-2014-image-classification-c2b3565a64e7